# Using split() in :value of <option> tag in vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js, drop-down-menu

I am tyring to use `split()` in `<option>` tag. the **AvaFac** is an `array` continaing `Name` and `Code` like `["XXX^101", "YYY^102"]`

The `split()` as show in the `<option>` tag throws error. Is there an another way to achieve this without using separate `array` to save the code.

```
<option v-for="fieldRows in avaFac" :value=fieldRows.split('^')[1]>
      <span class="custom__tag">
         <span>{{fieldRows}}</span>
      </span>
    </option>
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a method that splits your value.

```
methods:{
  splitValue(itemToSplit){
    return itemToSplit.split("^")[1]
  }
}
```

Take a look a this [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-995b4)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did try the same approach, but the returning value is not being set in the <select> tag. It comes as blank dropdown for  <span>{{fieldRows}}</span>. But the value field in <option> is setting properly. why didnt the dropdown values being set

Comment: Sorry both the values are being set to their places if the see them in developer tools option. but the dropdown values are not being set initially. is there something i need to change

Comment: Is there an error on the console? In my example, there are no errors, so you might miss something. Try to add this line `<select v-if="avaFac && avaFac.length > 0">`

Comment: There are no errors in the console. the data is being set to the <span> tag, but one initial value was supposed to be selected and it is not being selected after this code change in select dropdown

Comment: You can add `:selected="i === 0"` in the `option` tag so you can have the first element selected by default

Comment: <option v-for="fieldRows in avaFac" :value=splitfieldrows(fieldRows,1) :selected="i === 0">  is this right ? Because i dont see any change

Comment: As I can see you are using another method. I did not give you any method called `splitfieldrows`. So there is no way to help if I don't know what your function is doing.  Add some `code`

Comment: same method only, i just changed the name, sorry

Comment: Well, in that case, the `splitfieldrows` accepts one parameter, not two.

Comment: yes Sorry, i was sending 1 as second parameter for a internal condition.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend transforming your data into an array of objects using a computed property. Something like:

```js
computed: {
    preparedAvaFac() {
        return this.avaFac.map(row => {
             const rowObj = row.split("^");
             return {
                 name: row[0], 
                 code: row[1]
        }
    }
}
```

This will transform avaFac into something similar to

```
[
    {name: "XXX", code: "101"},
    {name: "YYY", code: "102"}
]
```

Then in your markup:

```html
<option v-for="fieldRows in preparedAvaFac" :value=fieldRows[1]>
    <span class="custom__tag">
       <span>{{fieldRows[0]}}</span>
    </span>
</option>
```